# Records in one table not present in another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to use LEFT JOIN, NOT EXISTS and NOT IN, where I want records from pursuit table, expect matching records from condition table using foreign key instance = id. When I execute the query, it shows empty (no records).

LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT p.id, p.dept
FROM 
pursuit p LEFT JOIN condition c USING (dept)
WHERE 
p.id = c.instance
```

NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT p.id, p.dept
FROM 
pursuit p 
WHERE 
p.id NOT EXISTS IN (SELECT c.instance FROM condiiton c)
```

NOT IN

```
SELECT p.id, p.dept
FROM 
pursuit p 
WHERE 
p.id NOT IN (SELECT c.instance FROM condiiton c)
```

TABLES

```
condition 

id instance dept
1     3      5
5     2      5
2     7      5
3     4      5
4     10     5
5     2      3
6    15      6    

pursuit 

  id   name  dept
  3    C1     5 
  2    C9     5
  7    C77    5
  4    C9     5
  10   C6     5  
 19   C23     5
 17   C45     5
 15   C12     5
 23   C33     5
```

3,2,7,4 = matching records of dept 5

19,17,15,23 = not matching records of dept 5

Output

```
id    name      dept
 19   C23         5
 17   C45         5
 15   C12         5
 23   C33         5
```

Comment: And well it should. What is your problem with the output? As we can see, for every pursuit id (3,7,2,10,15,4) there exists a condition row with p.id = c.instance. Thus, when you use NOT exists or NOT in, it correctly returns nothing.

Comment: George Menoutis - Do we have other way of improving the query.

Comment: What do you mean by "improve"? If you mean faster, then no, it's good as it is. Do you need something ELSE returned?

Comment: I don't understand why my question score has -2 votes. Stack Overflow looks for only standard developers or learners.

Comment: Please consider adding desired output.

Comment: @DDS : I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit2:

```
SELECT p.id, p.dept
FROM pursuit p LEFT JOIN condition c 
              on (p.id = c.instance and p.dep=c.dep)
WHERE c.instance IS NULL
```

this returns rows of pursuit not present in condition table

Comment: The query was working. It shows all the records from the both tables, but I want the records from only pursuit table.

Comment: query edited.. if you only need data from pursuit, just avoid the join

Comment: I want records from pursuit table, expect matching records from condition table So, in this case we need both the tables.

Comment: I'm looking for non-matching records from pursuit table by avoiding matching records from condition table.

Comment: still not clear: please add a table with expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
SELECT P.*
FROM pursuit p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM condition c 
                  WHERE p.id = c.instance
                  );
```

The only problem were with `NOT EXISTS` you haven't established any relation between them.